# ggplot Line and Segment Fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill

I'm looking to create a plot that looks similar to [this one on David Robinson's variance explained blog](http://varianceexplained.org/figs/2015-10-21-credible_intervals_baseball/jeter_plot-1.png):

[image: http://varianceexplained.org/figs/2015-10-21-credible_intervals_baseball/jeter_plot-1.png]

I think I have it down except for the fill that goes between the credible intervals and under the posterior curve. If anyone knows how to do this it would be great to get some advice.

Here's some sample code:

```
library(ebbr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

sample<- data.frame(id=factor(1:10), yes=c(20, 33, 44, 51, 50, 50, 66, 41, 91, 59), 
                total=rep(100, 10))

sample<-
  sample %>%
  mutate(rate=yes/total)

pri<-
  sample %>%
  ebb_fit_prior(yes, total)

sam.pri<- augment(pri, data=sample)

post<- function(ID){
  a<-
    sam.pri %>%
    filter(id==ID)

  ggplot(data=a, aes(x=rate))+
    stat_function(geom="line", col="black",  size=1.1, fun=function(x) 
      dbeta(x, a$.alpha1, a$.beta1))+
    stat_function(geom="line", lty=2, size=1.1,
                  fun=function(x) dbeta(x, pri$parameters$alpha,     pri$parameters$beta))+
    geom_segment(aes(x=a$.low, y=0, xend=a$.low, yend=.5), col="red", size=1.05)+
    geom_segment(aes(x = a$.high, y=0, xend=a$.high, yend=.5), col="red", size=1.05)+
    geom_segment(aes(x=a$.low, y=.25, xend=a$.high, yend=.25), col="red", size=1.05)+
xlim(0,1)
}

post("10")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually do it by generating the data to describe the curve manually, adding zero y values for the min and max of the shaded region, and using `geom_polygon()`.

```
library(ebbr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

sample <- data.frame(id = factor(1:10), yes = c(20, 33, 44, 51, 50, 50, 66, 41, 91, 59), 
                    total = rep(100, 10)) %>%
  mutate(rate=yes/total)

pri <- sample %>%
  ebb_fit_prior(yes, total)

sam.pri <- augment(pri, data = sample)

a <- sam.pri %>%
  filter(id == 10)

# Make the x values for the shaded region
x <- seq(from = a$.low, to = a$.high, length.out = 100)

# Make the y values for the shaded region
y <- dbeta(x, a$.alpha1, a$.beta1)

# Make a data.frame for the shaded region, including zeroes
shaded <- data.frame(x = c(x, a$.high, a$.low), y = c(y, 0, 0))

ggplot(data = a, aes(x = rate)) +
  stat_function(geom = "line", col = "black", size = 1.1, 
                fun = function(x)  dbeta(x, a$.alpha1, a$.beta1)) +
  geom_polygon(data = shaded, aes(x, y),
               fill = "red", alpha = 0.1) +
  stat_function(geom = "line", lty = 2, size = 1.1,
                fun = function(x ) dbeta(x, pri$parameters$alpha,     pri$parameters$beta)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = a$.low, y = 0, xend = a$.low, yend = 0.5), col = "red", size = 1.05) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = a$.high, y = 0, xend = a$.high, yend = .5), col = "red", size = 1.05) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = a$.low, y = .25, xend = a$.high, yend = .25), col = "red", size = 1.05) +
  xlim(0,1)
```

[image]